# shell script not running on terminal

Tags: gnome, gnome-terminal, scripts

I created a `scriptA.sh` on the desktop and make it executable then this was it content:

```
#!/bin/bash
sudo -u userA bash -c 'PACKAGE_PATH=/home/userA/package1; cd /home/userA/scripts'
```

I want to double click on this to open terminal and run the two commands in it and keep terminal opened. But what actually happens after double clicking it and choosing to `run with terminal` option, the terminal opens for a second and then closes itself. I don't know why this is happening, so I'd appreciate if anyone could please advise why this is happening and how to overcome it.

Comment: Are you logged in as 'userA'?

Comment: you mean through the os or terminal? I'm logged in to the system using `userA` and by default when I open a terminal its logged in using `userA` as well.

Comment: Then `sudo -u userA bash -c` seems unnessecary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably want to use `gksudo` if you want to start it from your Desktop. That will open a window asking you for your password.

```
#!/bin/bash
gksudo -u userA bash -c 'PACKAGE_PATH=/home/userA/package1; cd /home/userA/scripts'
```

Also to debug, you probably want to run that script in your terminal first. That way it will not close just after printing some error messages.

---

**Update**

One way to do that is to create a file as follow:

```
/home/user_name/.gnome2/panel2.d/default/launchers/script_name.desktop
```

Then put something like this in it:

```
#!/usr/bin/env xdg-open

[Desktop Entry]
Version=1.0
Type=Application
Terminal=false
Icon[en_US]=gdu-category-peripheral
Name[en_US]=Receiving fax
Exec=gksu /usr/bin/gnome-terminal
Comment[en_US]=Some description...
Name=My Script
Comment=Start my script
Icon=gnome-panel-launcher
```

That works great for me, in general. The gnome-terminal accepts parameters so you can change various settings.

Use `--working-directory=...` instead of your `cd ...` command. To get specific variables, you probably want to use the `--profile=...` option.

```
Exec=gksu -u userA /usr/bin/gnome-terminal --profile=/home/userA/profile --working-directory=/home/userA/scripts
```

Then create the profile script for the variable:

```
# In /home/userA/profile
PACKAGE_PATH=/home/userA/package1
```

Obviously you could add any other alias or anything else you need in the profile script.

Comment: I've tried `gksudo` but still same thing happening. the script `PACKAGE_PATH=/home/userA/package1; cd /home/userA/scripts` is working find if I manually opened a terminal and run it.

Comment: I'm not too sure what you are trying to do actually. That script doesn't do anything unless started in a terminal. If your point is to open a terminal in a specific folder and as root (sudo user), then you need to start a terminal and run that script in it.

Comment: I want to double click on this to open terminal and run the two commands in it and keep terminal opened. (question edited)

Comment: Okay, try the .desktop file. Before you could create those using a GUI interface, but in the latest versions of Ubuntu the GUI fails to work right so I have had to edit the file with a text editor. The result is the same though, once done, a double click works as expected.

Comment: I can't find this location `/home/user_name/.gnome2/panel2.d/default/launchers/` I can find only this `/home/user_name/.gnome2/` I can't find `panel2.d` I find  `keyrings` and `nautilus-scripts`

Comment: Hmmm... maybe you could search for .dekstop files in your home directory to see if you have any... Maybe it gets installed with something I have had for a long time... I have a package named `gnome-panel` and one called `gnome-panel-data`.

Answer (score 2):

By default, when you choose the option to "run in a terminal window", the (gnome-) terminal window closes after it is finished. It *does* open, since you mention it opens for a second. You can make it *stay* open by changing the setting it in your terminal profile:

From the (gnome-terminal) menu, choose "Edit" > "Profile Settings" > "Title and Command". In the option "When command exits" choose "Hold the terminal open".

That should work.

[image]

Comment: That's a good one to know about. Probably a lot easier to do than my solution of using a `.desktop` file.