# Terminal window closes within a second

Tags: system-installation, execute-command

I am new to Ubuntu.
Whenever I execute a .sh file, it closes within a second.
I need to install macbuntu but i cannot do so as i cannot see the output of the terminal window.
Can you please help?

Comment: Look here: http://askubuntu.com/a/527302/72216

Comment: How did you execute that?

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are just double-clicking on the file in the gui. Try this: open a terminal, locate the file you want to execute with

```
cd path/to/MacBuntu-10.10/
```

and then try

```
bash install.sh
```

Comment: Why `bash install.sh` instead of `./install.sh`?

Comment: @the_Seppi because this way i skipped the extra step of making the file executable with chmod